# Express JS POST method giving different value on same input

Tags: javascript, express, server, knex.js

In express js post method, with knex ORM on constructing a sql query for selecting entire with ** where ** condition, i'm seeing different output for same input

i tried using email string that is present in the DB table, i have used correct email once(got expected output), wrong email next(expected output), correct email(same as first, but wrong output)

```
DB_login = knex('login');

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    DB_login.where('email', '=', 'srinivaskandari97@gmail.com').select('hash').then(data => {
      console.log(data, 'srinivaskandari97@gmail.com');
    }).then(() => {
        DB_login.where('email', '=', 'srinivaskandari97@gmam').select('hash').then(data => {
        console.log(data,'srinivaskandari97@gmam' );
      }).then(() => {
          DB_login.where('email', '=', 'srinivaskandari97@gmail.com').select('hash').then(data => {
          console.log(data, 'srinivaskandari97@gmail.com');
          res.send('HI');
        });
       });

     });
  });
```

DB TABLE:
login:

```
 id |                             hash                             |            email
----+--------------------------------------------------------------+-----------------------------
 11 | $2b$05$lwQeP2dpcpd52VWMJ4JksuFJHC0BG.XDG/VnUzcQB4m2vFGP358Ae | sydneystriker4@gmail.com
 12 | $2b$05$H68bFc2sIjVhKzk1P7zvyO.vYXjYy0jFxBu9IQLIhN.557WHCuW2q | srinivaskandari97@gmail.com
```

OUTPUT CONSOLE:

```
[ { hash:
     '$2b$05$H68bFc2sIjVhKzk1P7zvyO.vYXjYy0jFxBu9IQLIhN.557WHCuW2q' } ] 'srinivaskandari97@gmail.com'   --- EXPECTED
[] 'srinivaskandari97@gmam'     --- EXPECTED
[] 'srinivaskandari97@gmail.com'--- UNEXPECTED, input is same as first one
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same builder for all of the queries, so all `where` calls are appended to the same builder.

You should use `clone()` if you don't want to change the initial builder.

```
DB_login = knex('login');

app.post('/', (req, res) => {
    DB_login.clone().where('email', '=', 'srinivaskandari97@gmail.com').select('hash').then(data => {
      console.log(data, 'srinivaskandari97@gmail.com');
    }).then(() => {
        DB_login.clone().where('email', '=', 'srinivaskandari97@gmam').select('hash').then(data => {
        console.log(data,'srinivaskandari97@gmam' );
      }).then(() => {
          DB_login.clone().where('email', '=', 'srinivaskandari97@gmail.com').select('hash').then(data => {
          console.log(data, 'srinivaskandari97@gmail.com');
          res.send('HI');
        });
       });

     });
  });
```

Comment: Thank you so much man. i have been scratching my head with this for a while. Great help. thank you